# Как показать определенный div только один раз на сайте?

Tags: html, cookie, php, javascript

Что есть: javaScript\jQuery, html\css, php.

Мне необходимо показать окно (div блок) один раз. Пользователь его может закрыть.

Как сделать так, чтобы это окно (div блок) больше не показывалось, при следующем заходе на сайт, и при переходе на другие страницы?

Уточнение: окно показывается в зависимости от результата работы php функции.

UPD.

Можно считать закрытым.

Большое спасибо Kremchik, последний вариант работает как надо.

UPD.

в google chrome 14.0.835.35 beta-m возможны странности с кукисами

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно использовать куки.

Comment: никогда с ними не сталкивался. гуглю...

Comment: В данном случае особо разбираться-то и не придётся. Я написал ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В начале любой странички пишете:

```
$first_time = false;
if (!isset($_COOKIE["название"])) {
    $first_time = true;
    setcookie("название", "любое_слово", time() + 3600*24*10, "/");
    /* помнить десять дней, куки действуют на всех страницах сайта */
}
```

В том месте, где выводится див:

```
if ($first_time) {
    my_echo_div();//короче вывод дива
}
```

Очень важный момет, что `setcookie()` должна вызываться именно в начале страницы, т.е. до любого вывода. Если будет сначала перенос строки, а потом открывающий `<?php` тег, то кукис не установится.

Ещё наверно стоит указать, что делать, если захочется сбросить кукисы:

```
setcookie("название", "", 0, "/");//устанавливаем эти же куки, только чтобы их срок истекал в далёком 70-ом :)
```

**PS** Вы указали, что у вас есть и php, а так всё это дело можно решить и с помощью js: [одна из многих статей](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

**PS** Если необходимо иметь возможность закрывать div, т.е. показывать его до тех пор, пока пользователь не закроет его, то возможное решение: javascrip-ом устанавливать куку при закритии. То есть убрать строчку setcookie() из php кода и перенести её аналог в js на странице. Полный вариант может выглядеть так:

```
<?php
    $first_time = false;
    if (!isset($_COOKIE["olole"])) {
        $first_time = true;
    }

    function my_echo_div() {
        echo '<a href="#" onclick="confirm()" id="noob">New member!</a><span id="old" style="display: none">Old member :)</span>';
    }
?>
<?php if($first_time) my_echo_div(); else echo "Old member :)" ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie (name, value, seconds) {
    if (typeof(seconds) != 'undefined') {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (seconds) * 1000);
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        var expires = "";
    }

    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function confirm() {
    setCookie("olole", "ololo", 10);
    document.getElementById("noob").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("old").style.display = "";
}
</script>
```

Comment: большое спасибо! сейчас попробую.

Comment: не работает. это может связано с тем, что я это все на вордпресе делаю, и у движка есть свой собственный механизм кукисов? щас попробую на просто странице

Comment: Ну может только если конфликт какой-то с именами. Если вы сделаете название куки "olole", то такого быть не может. Попробуйте потестировать с очень малым сроком действия, т.е. time() + 10 например. Подождите полминуты, зайдите на страничку, и вы должны увидеть div. Затем зайдите на другую страничку. Затем подождите ещё полминуты и обновите - вы должны снова увидеть div. Я правильно понял вашу задачу?) Показать какой-то элемент (див или текст, всё равно) только один раз для уникального посетителя и не показывать его в дальнейшем?

Comment: Если необходимо иметь возможность закрывать div, т.е. показывать его до тех пор, пока пользователь не закроет его, то возможное решение: javascrip-ом устанавливать куку при закритии. То есть убрать строчку setcookie() из php кода и перенести её в js на странице.

Comment: практически. да.(если пользователь нажмет на кнопку)

сейчас на пустой странице делаю, див просто не отображаеться
(еще когда смотрю ресурсы страницы - пишет, что тут кукисов нет)

Comment: о нет. все работает! мои извинения

Comment: думаю на вордпресе не работает потому, что я пишу код для шаблона. то есть где то в /wp-content/them/chtotam...

Comment: Возможно это результат вывода пробела, переноса строки, любого "echo", текста и пр. перед вызовом setcookie() :)

Comment: будем пробовать. спасибо.

Comment: Я привёл полный пример с JS если что, можете попробовать протестировать его отдельно от WP.

Answer (score 1):

Куки это славно, если дело касается не авторизованного юзера, если же вывод для зарегистрированных и авторизованных пользователей, то лучше вести контроль в БД.