# Выполнить функцию PHP через несколько секунд после старта страницы сайта

Tags: таймер, php, cookie

Привет.

На ХешКод я нашел вот такой [код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/25403/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-div-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5).

Код cookie хорошо работает. Спасибо, что вы есть.

**Вопрос**

Как сделать, чтобы функция:

```
function my_echo_div() {
        echo '<a href="#" onclick="confirm()" id="noob">New member!</a><span id="old" style="display: none">Old member :)</span>';
    }
```

выполнилась после старта страницы сайта через 30 секунд?

Comment: где страница и где сервер (php)

Comment: Как обычно в таких случаях: http://www.phpfaq.ru/na_tanke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему так

```
$hashcode = file_get_contents("html.html");

   echo $hashcode;
```

Подробности напишу на блоге Pixel.com

Answer (score 1):

PHP может только, скажем так, "сгенерить" Вам страницу, а некие функции через 30 секунд после загрузки напишите на JavaScript.

Ну а если уж очень хочется, можно пойти плохим путем и сделать что-то подобное:

```
<? $thisStr = '<a href="#">Ваш код</a>'; ?>
<script>
     setTimeout(function(){ document.write('<?=$thisStr?>'); }, 30000);
</script>
```

Но это плохая практика.

Comment: Ребята, Я сам запутался и Вас запутал.
Нужно выполнить через время не функцию PHP а то что она выполняет. Передавать PHP в JS я не буду. Как сделать наоборот?

Comment: Наоборот (из js в php) можно, используя ajax.

Comment: Почему так не работает?

$hashcode = 'html-код'

function my_echo_div() {
  echo '<script>setTimeout(function()
  { document.write("'.$hashcode.'"); }, 30000)</script>';
    }

Comment: @Viher, скорее всего из-за присутствия двойных кавычек внутри $hashcode, которые перекрывают друг друга с внешними. Посмотрите в консоль браузера на предмет ошибок и того, что получилось в html в итоге.

Comment: Двойные кавычки обязательное условия передачи переменной. Консоль пустая. HTML код выполняется через обратный слеш  id=\"бла-бла\" без пробелов! Проблема в том, что стили CSS не работают?